# Java- Default constructor with one initialized variable of type array and calling it in main

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have this program which has a class Ant where:

The default constructor initialises the instance variables queens to only 1
queen named “Beth” and `colonySize` to 100,000.

The defined constructor takes in two parameters and initialises the
corresponding instance variables.

The method `display`, shows the information about an ant in the format
below:

```
This ant colony has the following queens:
Queen 1: Beth
The colour of the ants: black
The approximate colony size: 100000
```

Here is what I have done:

```
public class Ant {

private String[] queens;
private String colour= "black";
private int colonySize;


public Ant(){
    queens[0]= "Beth";
    colonySize= 100000;
}

public Ant(String[] queens, int colonySize){
    this.queens[0]= queens[0];
    this.colonySize= colonySize;
}

public void display(){
    System.out.println("Queen 1: "+ this.queens[0]);
    System.out.println("Colour of the ants: "+colour);
    System.out.println("The size of the colony: "+ this.colonySize);
   }
}
```

The prob is arising when I am calling it in the main.

Main Class

```
public class MainAnts {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       Ant obj= new Ant();
       obj.display();

    }

}
```

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception (because I suppose that's not the right way to call the display method in the main since it has an array variable).

Comment: Stepping through the code with a debugger might help. Thats how most other people fix their code.

Comment: Java Arrays are fixed with the size you declare/construct them.  Your queens is empty.  Simplest fix is: `private String[] queens = {""};` but see the answer from Robert Kasperczyk for a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you never initialize your queens array. If you want to use ordinary array with fixed length then do:

```
    public Ant() {
        queens = new String[1000] //or whatever size you want
        queens[0] = "Beth";
        colonySize = 100000;
    }
```

Or you may want to use ArrayList:

```
    private List<String> queens;
    private String colour = "black";
    private int colonySize;


    public Ant() {
        queens = new ArrayList<>();
        queens.add("Beth");
        colonySize = 100000;
    }
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Queen 1: " + this.queens.get(0));
        System.out.println("Colour of the ants: " + colour);
        System.out.println("The size of the colony: " + this.colonySize);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `queens = new ArrayList<String>();` ?

Comment: Are there any advantages of specifying a type two times(declaration and definition)? I thought that this is redundant in this case.

Comment: Not so much here where they are only a few lines apart, but in general. YMMV.